# Why does Facebook's Open Graph protocol require an fb:admins or fb:app_id .. and what is the importance of this property?

Tags: html, facebook, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

I'm playing around with adding some [Facebook Open Graph meta tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) to my web site, to help with Facebook sharing of my website content.

One of the tags is this:

```
fb:admins or fb:app_id
```

> A comma-separated list of either Facebook user IDs or a Facebook
> Platform application ID that administers this page. It is valid to
> include both fb:admins and fb:app_id on your page.

Questions:

- What is the importance of this property?
- Administers *what* page?
- Why do we need to administer some page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I already answered on Facebook Dev Forum :

As described here : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

> Your page will appear in the "Likes and Interests" section of the user's profile, and you have the ability to publish updates to the user

1. Without this property you'll loose admin right on the Open Graph Facebook Page
2. Yep, when users likes your website's page, it'll generate an Open Graph Facebook Page :
   When users will try to go on it (by cliking on publications, or searching), it will redirect to your website's page.
3. To publish status updates to users news feed, create events, or add pictures related to this page.

Answer (score 0):

Also, having admins or an app_id means that the insights for that web page will show when you are logged in as that user, or looking at that app's insights. It is important to link everything together properly so you get a full overview of your interactions and users etc.